# How to reference a master page other than the "default" in custom Application Page

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, application-pages

I have a custom Application Page that's using `DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"` to get the associated master page. I'd like for this Application Page (and others) to use my custom Master Page that I created using the Design Manager. This master page is stored with the others at `[MappedDrive]:/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master`

In Site Settings, I can change the `System Master Page` to use my custom master page, which in turn will cause my Application Page to use it.

[image: Master page example]

However, I don't want *all* the administrative pages of SharePoint to have my custom site master page, I'd rather have them use *seattle* to have that native SharePoint feel. I only want the specific application pages that I'm creating to use my custom master page. How can I set the `DynamicMasterPageFile` attribute to reference my custom master page?

*SharePoint 2013 On-premise*

Comment: Open the page in an editor like notepad and change the master page.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf I know how to edit the page, but what URL do I change it to? As a note, ~masterurl/custom.master" will not work.

Comment: After reading the question again and doing some research it appears that it may not be easy to accomplish this. But can you just try to put a copy of the master page in the layouts directory and reference it in the application page like `DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/yourcustommaster.master"`

Comment: @NadeemYousuf That would be unfortunate, since keeping a separate copy of the master page is obviously duplicating data in different areas.

Comment: Did you have a look at this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgeoffro/archive/2009/06/22/master-pages-revisited-references-to-master-pages-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: @NadeemYousuf seems like a relevant post; I'll take a look.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf I don't understand why I can't reference the master page like /_catalogs/masterpage/CustomApp.master . If I navigate to [mysite]/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomApp.html (.html or .master), I can see it.

Comment: The application page resides in layouts directory. So _catalogs token won't work.